# How to spawn multiple prefab, with individual physics

Tags: unity-game-engine

I Did apply some of the responses , most likely in the wrong way.. this is still not working with this RAYCAST. What am I doing wrong here?

Want to spawn a prefab, which is a a ball, this ball is flying forward on flick finger on the screen.

What I want is to spawn OnClick FEW/Multiple of this prefab.

, prefab is spawning on Raycast Hit, BUT.. when I am flicking the object  EVERY prefab in the scene is moving in the same way.
If I flick first one in to the Left, it goes there, but If now I flick second one to right, BOTH go to the RIGHT, but I would like them to work independent. Maybe this is easy fix to this but I can't find answer. (I'm planning to have up to 30/50 of this prefabs, so attaching separate scripts would be bit time consuming)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class BallScript1 : MonoBehaviour
{
Vector2 startPos, endPos, direction;
 float touchTimeStart, touchTimeFinish;
 public float timeInterval = 5f;
 public float throwForceInXandY = 1f;
 public float throwForceinZ = 40f;



public static bool SpawnButtonAppear = true;
public static bool thrown = false;
public static bool moving = false;
public static bool fly = false;
public  bool Pressed = false;



Rigidbody rb;
public GameObject player;
public Vector3 originalPos;
public GameObject playerPrefab;

string touched;


void Start()
 {
     rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rb.isKinematic = true;
   
}

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    PlayerTest.clicked = true;
}


 void Update()
 {

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        RaycastHit _hit; Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out _hit))
        {
             touched = _hit.collider.tag;

            if (touched == "Player")
            {

                Invoke("spawned", 0.5f);

            }
        }
    }

    if (touched == "Player")
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            touchTimeStart = Time.time;
            startPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
        }


        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {

            fly = false;
            touchTimeFinish = Time.time;

            endPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

            direction = startPos - endPos;

            rb.isKinematic = false;
            rb.AddForce(-direction.x * throwForceInXandY, -direction.y * throwForceInXandY, throwForceinZ * timeInterval);

            BackWall.canSpawnNow = 1;

        }
    }

   

}



public void spawned()
{
    GameObject spawnedprefab = Instantiate(playerPrefab, new Vector3(originalPos.y, originalPos.x, originalPos.z), Quaternion.identity);
    Destroy(spawnedprefab, 5f);

}
```

Comment: What is `thrown`?

Comment: How exactly do you "flick" an object .. currently every single instance of your second script is listening to the global touch interactions ... There is nothing to determine which of the objects is the one that shall be used ... How would you like to decide which object is the one to be "flicked" ?

Comment: derHugo - thrown is a bool, I must copy wrong the script.
derHugo - But the script attached to prefab, only Works WHEN clicked on the object. So why the object that is NOT clicked is behaving like I would click it. 
Meaning. example: I touch/flick PREFAB1 to the left (it is already some distance from original position and going to the left side) than PREFAB2 appear and I touch/Flick him to the right. (so I'm not touching PREFAB1) but it behave like PREFAB2 (going to the right ) I'm bit confused here :)

Comment: well as said in the code there is nothing checking if you actually touched a certain object or not ... it just uses the touch .. which can be anywhere on the screen. You could e.g. use `Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position)` but it is unclear how exactly your objects look like ... e.g. do they have colliders? etc

Comment: If the bool is not the problem, +1 to Mr @derHugo's Raycast proposal

Comment: DerHugo - tried to implement this Raycast, probably did it wrong way.. can you give me some advice? what am I doing wrong as this is not working, I updated my code.

Comment: DerHugo- it's a square object with one box collider.

Answer (score -1):

The `thrown` variable is not declared inside your class, so when you set it to true you are setting it true for all the instances of the class.

Declare the `bool thrown;` inside the `EnemySpawn` class, so that `OnMouseDown`, only the corresponding intance's `thrown` variable is set to true.

Comment: I have it, declared.. must had copy something wrong. (the script is working) so that is not the problem, I have problem that Every spawned prefab behave the same. as I described  in my original question.

Comment: OK, as the declaration was not there at the beginning I thought that could be the problem.  It's true that the code would not compile without the declaration there, but yet I'm still working in my mental compilation superpowers